# SQL CASE WHEN in table

Tags: sql

I have two tables: table1 and table2 both with one column for ID. I want to create a column in table1 that displays 'Y' if ID in table1 is in table2 and 'N' if it is not.

Currently, I am using:

```
Select id, case when id in (table2) then 'Y' else 'N' end as in_table2 
from table1
```

However, since both tables are very big, the query is taking forever. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `exists`:

```
Select t1.id,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as in_table2 
from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be much quicker and efficient than using exists/subqueries:

```
    SELECT  t1.id ,
            CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL 
                THEN 'N'
                ELSE 'Y'
            END AS in_table2
    FROM    table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

By left joining you maintain visibility of the records on table2, and if the ID is null, you know it exists on table1 but not on table2, so you can safely use a case statement to show Y or N based on t2.id.